# sed - deleting n lines preceeding and following the matching pattern

Tags: linux, sed

Deleting "n" lines following the matching pattern is easy using something like:

```
IFM_MOUNT="/opt/insiteone/fuse-mount2/ifm"
sed -i "\|$IFM_MOUNT|,+6 d" smb.conf (deletes lines matching and next 6 lines)
```

But my problem is, i wish to delete 2 lines preceeding the matching pattern as well.

How to accomplish it?
The file i will be invoking the command is a Samba configuration file which looks like this:

```
[DCCAArchive1]
        comment = DCCA Archive File System
        path = /opt/insiteone/fuse-mount1/ifm
        read only = No
        public = yes
        case sensitive = yes
        writable = yes
        create mask=0777
        guest ok = Yes

[DCCAArchive2]
        comment = DCCA Archive File System
        path = /opt/insiteone/fuse-mount2/ifm
        read only = No
        public = yes
        case sensitive = yes
        writable = yes
        create mask=0777
        guest ok = Yes

[DCCAArchive3]
        comment = DCCA Archive File System
        path = /opt/insiteone/fuse-mount3/ifm
        read only = No
        public = yes
        case sensitive = yes
        writable = yes
        create mask=0777
        guest ok = Yes
```

Comment: give this a try, if it solved your problem. `awk -v RS="" '!/[/]opt[/]insiteone[/]fuse-mount2[/]ifm/' yourInput` I put it here in comment instead of answer, because it didn't count the `n` lines, it checks the "data block" as unit.

Comment: @Kent: Yes, it solves. But I am not sure, why the gap between 2 data blocks reduces to none, which perhaps Samba might not accept.

Comment: Samba accepts that, but it'll be a problem if there is no gap to start with. Still, treating the input blockwise seems like a saner idea than going by lines. If you have GNU awk, try `awk -v RS="(^|\n)[[]" -v path="$IFM_MOUNT" '!index($0, path) { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' filename`. (Although that is still hackish -- what if the path appears in a comment? What you really want to do is to use something like Python's configparser module or so).

Comment: @Wintermute: Ohhhh wow...that was super cool, please provide an answer for the benefit of others as well, however I will still wait, if sum1 answers from sed perspective, since that's what the question all about, but thanks..this solves as well.

Comment: I don't think sed is a good tool for this -- using shell variables in sed code is rarely a good idea (code injection becomes possible). @Kent has the right idea of splitting the input into blocks, which awk does well; my suggestion was just to use a different record separator to avoid the problem of missing blank lines (at the cost of making the code GNU-specific).

Comment: Don't use the term `pattern` as it's ambiguous. Are you searching for a string or a regexp or something else? It looks like the answers so far are assuming a regexp but that doesn't seem to match your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented, if the format was fixed, (empty lines between data blocks), this line would do the job:

```
awk -v RS="" '!/PATTERN/' input
```

if it was not in this case, you can try this awk one-liner:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}/PATTERN/{for(i=NR-2;i<=NR+6;i++)d[i]=1}
     END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(!d[i])print a[i]}' input
```

a test

- with `ifm` as simplified `PATTERN`
- no empty lines between "data blocks"
- follows your rule: remove lines `hit-2 -> hit+6`

  ```
  kent$  cat f
  fooooooooo
  [DCCAArchive1]
          comment = DCCA Archive File System
          path = /opt/insiteone/fuse-mount1/ifm
          read only = No
          public = yes
          case sensitive = yes
          writable = yes
          create mask=0777
          guest ok = Yes
  barrrrrrrrrrrr
  [DCCAArchive2]
          comment = DCCA Archive File System
          path = /opt/insiteone/fuse-mount2/ifm
          read only = No
          public = yes
          case sensitive = yes
          writable = yes
          create mask=0777
          guest ok = Yes

  kent$  awk  '{a[NR]=$0}/ifm/{for(i=NR-2;i<=NR+6;i++)d[i]=1}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(!d[i])print a[i]} ' f
  fooooooooo
  barrrrrrrrrrrr
  ```

### Edit

use pattern from shell variable:

```
kent$  PAT="/fuse-mount2/ifm"

kent$  awk -v p="$PAT" '{a[NR]=$0}{if(match($0,p)>0){for(i=NR-2;i<=NR+6;i++)d[i]=1}}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(!d[i])print a[i]} ' f                                          
fooooooooo
[DCCAArchive1]
        comment = DCCA Archive File System
        path = /opt/insiteone/fuse-mount1/ifm
        read only = No
        public = yes
        case sensitive = yes
        writable = yes
        create mask=0777
        guest ok = Yes
barrrrrrrrrrrr
```

Comment: Sorry did you test it, with the pattern something like: `IFM_MOUNT=/opt/insiteone/fuse-mount2/ifm` The file is printed as-is. I was referring to your one-liner

Comment: @kingsmasher1 you have to either esacpe the `/` or put it in `[/]`, check my comment under your question.

Comment: Got it, unfortunately my pattern will be in a shell variable, which is the problem :( So i need to tweak that? I wish there was a more cleaner way.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 check the edit, I used `match()` function in with `if'

Comment: Upvote. That worked great as well, apart from what `Watermark` suggested above in comments. Thank You.

Comment: No need for `match($0,p)>0` when you could just use `$0~p` but it REALLY looks like the OP wants to search for a string not a regexp (there goes that infuriatingly ambiguous term "pattern" again!) so you should be using `index($0,p)` instead. Also, when using `RS=""` it's almost always desirable to set `ORS="\n\n"` so you get a blank line between the output records.

Answer (score 0):

You use the following `sed` command:

```
sed -r ':a;N;s~([^\n]*\n){2}[^\n]*'"$search"'\n~~;ba' file
```

The command works basically as a loop. `:a` marks a label at the loop start. `N` reads the next line of input and appends it to the pattern buffer. `s~([^\n]+\n){2}PATTERN\n~~` will remove the pattern and two lines before it. Note that I'm using `~` as the delimiter since the input data contains the "standard" delimiter `/`. `ba` will branch back to the start of the loop. On the end of input the modified file gets printed `$p`.

Btw, it is simple to change the pattern to any amount of preceding lines by simply changing the `2` in the search pattern to whatever you want.

Comment: ` sed -r ':a;N;s/([^\n]+\n){2}$IFM_MOUNT[^\n]+\n){2}//;t;ba' smb.conf`
`ERROR: sed: -e expression #1, char 45: Unmatched ) or \)`

Comment: @kingsmasher1 Sorry, fixed that

Comment: Sorry I tried that, though no errors this time, but all the lines, including the pattern are displayed, or in other words no change in the file at all. Here is what I did: `sed -r ':a;N;s/([^\n]+\n){2}$IFM_MOUNT\n([^\n]+\n){2}//;t;ba' smb.conf`

Comment: Probably your pattern is the problem. Let me give an example with the file you shown in the question. sec..